# nginx deny access to .log file extension

Tags: php, regex, nginx, pcre

how to prevent nginx from accessing .log file extension , I have this nginx config

```
location ~* (\.ini|\.log|\.conf)$ {
     deny all;
     error_page 403 =404 / ;
 }
```

but above code is not working anyways?
I'm not good enough in pcre regex handling.

Answer (score 17):

Worked for me.

```
location ~\.(ini|log|conf)$ {
     deny all;
     error_page 403 =404 / ;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know the ( ) match pattern was doing that job

Comment: @user3453753 Welcome... :)

Comment: @user3453753 You just need to replace `~*` with `~`. The changed in expression is a better way of writing expression. If you only replace  `~*` with `~` that will also work. :)